# Z-INDEX Issue, and does order of the code matter in html

Tags: html, css

**Excuse me for my newbie question as I just recently started web developing.**

So I was building a website, and then I put my `<image.svg>` code directly below `<body>` nested in a `<div>`, but it pushes my element down. I tried using `<position>` and `<z-index>` but it didn't work. I tried to find other guides for this specific problem but there are none available as of this moment.

Here is the code:

```
<body>
<div id="background">(LONG SVG CODE)</div>
<header>
        <div>
              <div id="logo">Logo</div>
              <p>Text</p>
        </div>
</header>
<div class="navbar" id="navbar">
        <ul>
             <li>Text</li>
             <li>Text</li>
        </ul>
</div>
    <div class="item">
             <h1>Text</h1>
             <p>Text.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
#background {
    position: center center fixed;
    z-index: 1;
}

header {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

#navbar {
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
}

.item {
     z-index: 4;
     position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The background is not going behind other elements instead it pushes them down the website.

Comment: What is your goal with putting the svg in the div?

Comment: My SVG is my background in my website . I already found the problem too, thanks for taking time to help me tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your would have your background under all, please make your "div" absolute width neccesary position and dimensions

```
 #background{
  position:absolute:
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
 }
```